# Matplotlib plot shrink when the legend is large

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a problem that occur when the legend of the plot is large, as you can see in this picture (when the legend's size is normal everything look great):
[image]

This is the code that add the legend to the plot:

```py
        for i in range(num_of_batches):
            cluster_patch = Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='w', label='batch ' + str(i + 1),
                                   markerfacecolor=cmap(i), alpha=0.2, markersize=8)
            clusters_patches.append(cluster_patch)
        # Create the user groups legend
        for i in range(num_of_clusters_by_condition_space):
            wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=27)
            limited_length_label_list = wrapper.wrap(text=str(list(partition.keys())[i]))
            limited_length_label_string = '\n'.join(limited_length_label_list)
            cluster_patch = Line2D((0, 0), (0, 0), markeredgecolor='black', markerfacecolor='none', linestyle='',
                                   marker=Utilities.get_smap(i),
                                   markeredgewidth=2, markersize=8,
                                   label=limited_length_label_string)
            clusters_patches.append(cluster_patch)
        legend = plt.legend(handles=clusters_patches, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), fontsize=10,
                            labelspacing=2)
```

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: The shrinking is probably caused by `set_aspect('equal')` or some variation thereof. You can tackle the problem putting the legend above or below the plot, or by making multiple columns (e.g. `plt.legend(...., ncol=5)`). See also [this guide](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html).

Comment: Not a complete example but I’d assume you are using tight_layout or constrained_layout somehow.  Take the legend out of the layout using leg.set_in_layout(False)

Comment: @JodyKlymak You are right, I used ```tight_layout```. When I try using ```set_in_layout(False)``` the legend disappeared, do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Depends on your use case.  You can save as `fig.savefig('name.png', bbox_inches='tight')` and that will expand the bounds to include anything.  You can also call plot_layout and then adjust the right hand side manually to accommodate.

Comment: @JodyKlymak The result I posted here is done when use ```bbox_inches='tight```, do you have any other suggestion how to expand the plot automatically?